# Checking a imploded string against comma separated column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to check like    `where (1,2,3) match (column2)` here column2 itself a comma seperated string, if any any value in column2 we need to get that row. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u want like this `where column2 in(1,2,3)`????

Comment: yes but column2  also a comma separated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

```
WHERE column2 IN (1,2,3)
```